# Why is my callback function not working inside a nested function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sockets

I'm using the callback function like this with Socket.io

```
loadData(callback) {

var client = new SyncClient(this.socket, this.project);
this.client = client; //From my data function

    client.on("connected", () => {
        this.values = client.getData();
        callback(client);
    }
}
```

But I got this message in my console : `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function` when I'm calling my  function `loadData`.

I think the callback() is trying his parent and his parent is the function created inside the `client.on` and not the `loadData(callback)` ? Or the problem is something else?

In my mounted I call my `loadData()` this way :

```
mounted() {
    this.loadData(this.client)
}
```

Comment: So where in the world do you call `loadData` ? Sounds like you are not passing in a function.....

Comment: This error tells you that whatever callback is, its not a function and can't be called like this: `callback()`. Try logging it to see what it trully is.

Comment: l'm sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the received data (res) from `.find` callback and pass it to your callback function:

```
socket.on('getSettings', function (data, callback) {

    console.log('Settings are broadcasted.');

    lmsSettings.find({}, function (err, res {
        callback(false, res); 
    });
});
```